# Query a Ext js form which contains a value ignoring case sensitive

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

I have a list of forms in a contianer. I just want to query all forms where value of any fields in the form starts with my passed value.

```
mainContainer.query('form > field[value^=Account]');
```

it is working fine and retrieving all the fields which starts with Account. But it is matching exact case. I Just want to ignore the case and all the fields even if the value is in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [`matcher`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query-property-matchers) and using regular expressions to accomplish this. The property `matchers` is already there. It's an array of objects, so just push your own `matcher` to it.

The matchers out-of-the-box:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/source/Query.html#Ext-dom-Query-property-matchers